# JqGrid PDF export in Arabic showing invalid character

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, jqgrid, export-to-pdf

I have created multiple reports in JqGrid but facing issue to import pdf in arabic language, it shows invalid character for all arabic words, I tried many ways but useless if anybody have experience like this share it.
Report Image showing Name column with arabic text
[image]

used Jquery code to export:

```
 $("#export").on("click", function () {
                $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("exportToPdf", {
                    title: 'jqGrid Export to PDF',
                    orientation: 'portrait',
                    pageSize: 'A4',
                    description: 'description of the exported document',
                    customSettings: null,
                    download: 'download',
                    includeLabels: true,
                    includeGroupHeader: true,
                    includeFooter: true,
                    regional:'ar',
                    fileName: "jqGridExport.pdf"
                })
            })
```

used libraries:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/ecmascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/5.5.1/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/5.5.1/js/i18n/grid.locale-ar.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.26/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.26/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous" ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/5.5.1/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

Comment: Hello. To be a honest we never test the export to pdf with Arabic. The reason for this is that pdfmake officially does not support Arabic export. There are some solutions using other fonts and we will try to test the export with these fonts. In the meantime you can test it to. One lib that I will try is [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/using-pdf-export-fonts/)